# Realtime interaction with CesiumJS

Tags: python, simulator, cesiumjs, satellite

**Question**:
Is it possible to interact with CesiumJS in real time.
If not. Is there another option to achieve the goal.

**Goal**:
Creating a satellite simulation with Python and CesiumJS.
Python calculates the trajectory and the attitude of the satellite.
CesiumJS Returns a video stream of the simulated satellite.

**Edit**:
The attitude is calculated by the returned video stream.
The satellite should track a specific Region-of-Interest (ROI).
-> Can CesiumJS return a video stream or pictures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes, you can send data to CesiumJS in real time.  You do need to write your own JavaScript code to receive that data and update Cesium's graphics.

But for something like a satellite, where the trajectory is so predictable in advance, sending real-time data is not advised.  It would be better to have your Python app pre-calculate the entire trajectory, and send that over to CesiumJS by way of CZML.  Then, Cesium can play it back in real-time, or allow the user to move simulation time forwards and backwards.  [Here's an example](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=CZML.html).

See also my answer describing Cesium's [Entities vs. Graphics Primitives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58839419/836708), which describes how one layer of Cesium's API is tailored to graphics that move along known paths, and a lower layer of the API is for primitives that need frequent, real time updates.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. I edited the question. The trajectory is indeed predictable. But the attitude is not. The attitude should be calculated in real time based on the satellites view/camera.

Comment: Cesium will use WebGL to render an image into a canvas, but the API doesn't directly return the image data programmatically.  Sometimes a canvas image can be read back by JS (`canvas.toDataURL()`), but Cesium talks to remote imagery providers which can create a "dirty canvas" security problem, where the browser prevents the final image from being read back as pixels.  Using local imagery like NaturalEarthII can avoid this issue.

Comment: I could imagine the trajectory coming in via CZML or `SampledPositionProperty`, and the attitude being applied as `entity.orientation` quaternions later.  I've never done it quite like that but it should work.